# Reset variable on every new session using localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage, session-storage

I am trying to run something only once at the beginning of the user session spanning multiple pages.

I was trying to use sessionStorage to test if a variable exists which defaults to false initially, but it is not persisting in some browsers due to a JavaScript redirect in the script:

```
window.location.href
```

Is there a way to mimic this with localstorage which persists more reliably?

i.e. to do something only once at the beginning of each new user session. The session may have multiple pages so a single javascript variable won't work.

update: as requested in the comments, the basic logic is:

1. new session opened.
2. redirect once to last page viewed.
3. set redirected to true. to prevent this from happening again.

I realize there are other ways to do this besides localstorage. would be nice to use that though if possible.

Comment: How do you define session? Opening a page when no other page of the same site is open? Opening a page after a long break? Time between logging in and logging out? Something else?

Comment: You might want to describe what kind of variable you want to store. Or better your business logic, so the community could help you better.

Comment: A javascript redirect through assignment to `location.href` should not drop a session. In *which* browsers do you experience this?

Comment: @Bergi firefox on my windows 7 firefox 61 though it works fine on chrome and firefox on windows 10

Comment: @exebook updated

Comment: Use ... cookies?

Answer (score -1):

you could check if the item already exists or if it is null with: 
`localStorage.getItem("itemname");`

If it doesnt exists (== null) it is the first "run" so you could set it to prevent further loop execution. use:
`localStorage.setItem("itemname", "notNull");`

Comment: right but what about next session tomorow or a week later? it will not be null then on the first run

Comment: at the next session it will be the same value as it had on the last session

Comment: ... but you could set it null with o onclose event if client window gets closed